# oracle sql join Ignore a table if not present

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a query which is used is different deployments (regions). Now, the query needs to be updated to join a new table.However, the new_table is available only is one deployment but not in the other.
Can we have a join which ignores a table based on some conditions? We want to have a single query which can be used in all deployments.

e.g. currently the join contains tables:
table_A, table_B, table_C.
new table needs to be added to the join say 'table_X'.
This 'table_X' is available only in regionA but not in regionB.

Comment: No.  Create an empty table on all deployments.

Comment: Can you use a pl/sql procedure? In this case you can use ALL_TABLES to find if the table exists and execute initial query or extended one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing an outer join to the table, then you only need to create an empty table_X in all regions

If you need to do an inner join, with the above, you have to translate inner join to outer join, and a condition of: (table_x.join_id is not null or region != 'region a')